# Does this error message mean I can use pattern matching in for loops?

Tags: rust

I do not expect the following code to work, but as part of grammar exploration, I tried in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1ad622f71b108b8b6dccd9b650688635&version=stable&mode=debug):

```
fn main() {
    struct EOF {};
    let lines = vec![Ok("line 1"), Ok("line 2"), Err(EOF {})];
    for Ok(line) in lines {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

The error message is

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in `for` loop binding: `Err(_)` not covered
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     for Ok(line) in lines {
  |         ^^^^^^^^ pattern `Err(_)` not covered
```

According to the message above it looks like I only need to add a match arm for the `Err` case. But what is the right grammar to do so?

Comment: To answer the intent of the question (using Ok in for loop), it is possible to achieve the same effect using: `for foo in bar.into_iter().flatten()`. Even better than using `flat_map`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use *patterns* as the binding in a `for` loop, but not *refutable* patterns. [The difference between refutable and irrefutable patterns is described here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html), but the gist of it is, if a pattern could fail, you can't use it in a `let` statement, a `for` loop, the parameter of a function or closure, or other places where the syntax specifically requires an irrefutable pattern.

An example of an irrefutable pattern being used in a `for` loop might be something like this:

```
let mut numbers = HashMap::new();
numbers.insert("one", 1);
numbers.insert("two", 2);
numbers.insert("three", 3);

for (name, number) in &numbers {
    println!("{}: {}", name, number);
}
```

`(name, number)` is an irrefutable pattern, because any place where it type checks, it will match. It type checks here because the items being iterated over (defined by the implementation of [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) for `&HashMap`) are tuples. You could also write the above as

```
for tuple in &numbers {
    let (name, number) = tuple;
    println!("{}: {}", name, number);
}
```

because `let` is another place where only irrefutable patterns are allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, [you can use patterns in many places](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html), but not all of them allow you to conditionally branch when there are multiple possible patterns.

A `for` loop is one place where you cannot add conditions. That's what the error is telling you with "refutable pattern": there's a pattern that will not be handled. Instead, you mostly use the pattern to perform *destructuring* of the loop variable:

```
struct Thing {
    foo: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let things = vec![Thing { foo: 1 }, Thing { foo: 2 }, Thing { foo: 3 }];
    for Thing { foo } in things {
        println!("{}", foo);
    }
}
```

Conditional:

- `match`
- `if let`
- `while let`

Unconditional:

- `for`
- `let`
- function parameters

Answer (score 4):

> But what is the right grammar to do so?

This gets the result you want:

```
fn main() {
    struct EOF;
    let lines = vec![Ok("line 1"), Ok("line 2"), Err(EOF)];
    for line in lines.into_iter().flat_map(|e| e) {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

Note that you can use `flat_map` here because `Result` implements the `into_iter` method provided by the `IntoIterator` trait.

This is another option using `if let`:

```
fn main() {
    struct EOF;
    let lines = vec![Ok("line 1"), Ok("line 2"), Err(EOF)];
    for result in lines {
        if let Ok(line) = result {
            println!("{}", line);
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to stop iteration on an `Err` case:

```
fn main() {
    struct EOF;
    let lines = vec![Ok("line 1"), Ok("line 2"), Err(EOF), Ok("line 3") ];
    let mut lines_iter = lines.into_iter();
    while let Some(Ok(line)) = lines_iter.next() {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```