# Match with a variable vs match with a placeholder?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let f = 1;

    match f {
        foo => {
            println!("{}", foo); // prints "1"
        }
    };

    match f {
        _ => {
            println!("{}", f); // prints "1"
        }
    };
}
```

Is there any difference between the two matches? And could anyone point me where the first match is documented? The Rust book (until chapter 9) seems only mention the placeholder `_`, but not "you can put any name (e.g., `foo` in this case) as the match condition".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are just patterns. [Patterns are documented in more details further in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html). There are many forms of patterns:

- Constants: `1`, `FOO`
- `enum` destructuring: `Some(y)`, `None`
- `struct` destructuring: `Point { x, y }`
- Tuple destructuring: `(42, foo)`
- Bindings: `foo`, `foo @ (42, bar)`
- Ranges: `1 ... 42`
- Placeholder: `_`
- etc.

There is no difference here between your two examples, however, named patterns are not often seen as a top-level pattern in a `match` expression, but rather in sub-patterns, such as `Some(foo)`. Named patterns are however extremely common for function parameters and `let` bindings.

Comment: Interesting, function parameters and let bindings are implemented as patterns?

Comment: @Helin Yes, and `for` loop bindings too. They are all different kinds of irrefutable bindings. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50644111/3650362) (I answered) addresses the meaning of *irrefutable*.

Comment: Though patterns in function parameters IMHO are not idiomatic. Using them would blur the line between interface and implementation, and make the interface harder to read for the user of the function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NoisyDrop(&'static str);
impl Drop for NoisyDrop {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{self:?} dropped");
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let v = NoisyDrop("With placeholder");
        match v {
            _ => {
                println!("Inside match arm");
            }
        }
        println!("After match arm");
    }
    
    println!();
    
    {
        let v = NoisyDrop("With name");
        match v {
            _foo => {
                println!("Inside match arm");
            }
        }
        println!("After match arm");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96bbacac71cbe79a8ccfc4a5a88ff400).

This prints:

```
Inside match arm
After match arm
NoisyDrop("With placeholder") dropped

Inside match arm
NoisyDrop("With name") dropped
After match arm
```

This is because when we use an identifier pattern (`_foo`) the matched variable is moved into the arm and dropped at the end of it. This also means that any attempt to use it after the `match` will result in an error. On the other hand, when we match with a wildcard (`_`) the variable is not moved. Thus, we can use it after the `match`, and it also means that it is dropped at the end of the scope and not of the `match`.