# What is let Foo(bar) = zar in Rust?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I was reading https://www.abubalay.com/blog/2018/04/08/recursive-ascent and it does something that I couldn't understand

```
let Elements(array) = elements;
```

What does that expression means? Is it creating the `array` variable? What about the `Elements(...)`!?

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644111/does-this-error-message-mean-i-can-use-pattern-matching-in-for-loops is another question that has to do with patterns that you may find useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a destructuring assignment. It just takes value out of a struct or enum:

```
struct Elements(Vec<&'static str>);

fn main() {
    let elements = Elements(vec!["hello", "world"]);
    let Elements(array) = elements;
    println!("array: {:?}", array); // prints array: ["hello", "world"]
}
```

You can use patterns in many places in Rust. Even in [let statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#let-statements). Just be sure that the pattern is [irrefutable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html).